# NameError for simple nonlocal binding

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to use a decorator to give a function access to a particular variable whenever it's called. For instance,

```
def make_x_available(fn):
    def decorated():
        x = 5
        return fn()
    return decorated

@make_x_available
def print_x():
    print(x)
```

`5` here stands for an arbitrary expression to be evaluated each time the function `fn` is called, and to be bound to the name `x`.

Instead of `print_x` walking up the stack to find x's value of 5 as I expected, it raises `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`.

How would I go about achieving this? And why is this error caused?

Comment: The cause is that **scope** of variables is set at function definition time, while resolution happens at run time. First your undecorated `print_x` is created, which sees only local and global scope, then your decorator runs, it creates own scope with `x` to which `print_x/fn` does not have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `x` as an argument to the function:

```
def make_x_available(fn):
    def decorated():
        x = 5
        return fn(x)
    return decorated

@make_x_available
def print_x(x):
    print(x)

print_x()
```

**Output**

```
5
```

Alternatively, you can use keyword arguments:

```
def make_x_available(fn):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['x'] = 5
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

@make_x_available
def print_x(*args, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs['x'])

print_x()
```

**Output**

```
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what it could be used for, but this would work:

```
from functools import wraps

def make_x_available(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        decorated.x = 5
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

@make_x_available
def print_x():
    print(print_x.x)

print_x()
```

prints:

```
5
```

**Note**:  When you write a decorator, **always** use `functools.wraps` to keep the name, docstring, and other attributes of the decorated function.